# Why do we need objects monitor if there is only thread

Tags: java

Running will start from the main method and if in some method i am using this.wait() without synchronized block, it will throw illegalStateMonitorException.

If there is only one thread why can't it wait, why should we use locking here. Thread is not going to perform any other task also. It could have waited there.

I am not understanding why locking is needed if there is single thread.

```
public class waitSleepCheck extends Thread{

    public void method() throws InterruptedException ,IllegalMonitorStateException{

        this.wait(1000);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
        waitSleepCheck object = new waitSleepCheck();
        object.method();
    }

}
```

Comment: On a side note please follow Java Naming conventions

Comment: Because the JVM has no idea how many threads may be running in the system or when they might be started...

Comment: Do you just want your thread to sleep? Because [Thread.sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) does that.

Comment: How will java know that you are going to have only one thread in your program? You can possibly have the thread wait now and start a thread later on in the program.

Answer (score 5):

`Object.wait` isn't "wait this long". It's "wait for some other thread to do something". The forms that take arguments are "wait for some other thread to do something, but get bored and stop after this long". You need to hold the object's lock to ensure proper synchronization with the thread that will notify you that the thing you're waiting for got done. It doesn't make sense to use the method in a single-threaded context.

If you just want to wait for a certain length of time, [`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is the method you want.

Comment: Well strictly speaking it is not "wait for some other thread to do something".  It is "wait for some other thread to notify / notifyAll me".  Whether it has (or hasn't) done something is application specific.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have called a method that ["causes the current thread to wait until another thread ..."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29), and so isn't appropriate in the first place for a single-threaded application.

Answer (score 0):

`synch(lockObj) {Object.wait()}` means that you wait until another thread signal you (see `Object.notify()`). In the underlying system, these methods are translated to [`wait(lockObj);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [pulseevent(target);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Which handles do yo think JVM will sumbit to them? If you do not specify the lock object then java has no idea which sync object (aka lock) you want to communicate over.